# Set listview header size programmatically

Tags: android, layout, dimensions

I have a ListView with header and I need to set header size programmatically depending on screen size. So it fills nearly whole screen. How can I do that? I found a way to get screen height, but it is the full height of the display, containing phone status bar height.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394514/how-to-generate-a-listview-with-headers-above-some-sections

Comment: is it looks like what i'm searching for?

Comment: In that link,see the solved answer,that show how to generatye the custom header of the listview.There you can do the tamp to get you output.

Comment: How can it help my needs? I know how to implement custom list rows and add header. I need to find out the size of notificationbar!

Answer (score 6):

if you are setting the header to the ListView by inflating a layout, like this:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, lv, false);
lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

you can change the height of the layout `R.layout.header` using

```
header.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You can get Notification or Status Bar height using this code here:

[Height of statusbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355367/height-of-statusbar/3356263#3356263#answers-header)

Comment: the question is mostly not about setting the height, but about getting it. I can get the full height of the display (480x800 on my phone), but i need to set header height to <screenHeight - notificationBarHeight - smthElse>. So I need to get notificationBarHeight, cause I suppose it could differ between different devices.

Comment: so you got your screen height, and smthElse, all you need is notificationBarHeight? I mean what height you exactly want?

Comment: yes, you may say I need notificationBarHeight. But I dont want to hardcode it, cause, I suppose, it may vary between different devices

Comment: check the link provided in the answer