# How to simply add header in a Listview ?

Tags: android, listview

I made a listView, now is there a simple way to add hearders in it ?
For example, make something like this

```
List.add("a")
list.addheader("Number")
list.add("1")
.
.
Widget_List_Adapter adapter = new Widget_List_Adapter(this, list);
.
.
.
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using [`ListView#addHeaderView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29).

As a warning, you must call this method *before* calling `setAdapter()` or `setListAdapter()`, just like your pseudo-code example.

Answer (score 1):

you could define a layout with a header layout followed by the listview. in the header layout you can define a textview that you can change in your code

Answer (score 0):

The `addHeaderView()` option only works to add a static header at the top of your list.  If you want to add section headers, you'll have to do a considerable amount of extra work.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394514/how-to-generate-a-listview-with-headers-above-some-sections) should lead you down the proper path to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

There's no section List(Table) View in Android, you can just add one top header, but if you want to make something like sectioned table view  like IOS, here are some better resources.

[android-section-list](http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/)
Just use this library it is awesome.

[android-amazing-listview](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)
This one is also very user, even it allows you to load more functionality like FB.

How ever you can also make your own custom list, here is the complete [blog.](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/)